# How to verify Integrity of ISO file with these constraints?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, data-integrity

I have a Windows 7 Desktop PC. My secondary HDD (SATA Internal) has developed a few bad sectors. Now its state is being reported as Caution in CrystalDiskInfo tool. I have already taken backup of my important data onto other storage devices like my SSD & Pen Drives.

One partition holds various ISO files. These files are nothing but ISO images of my various personal DVDs as a backup. Some DVDs were quite old and are already trashed because eventually later they were no longer getting detected.
It’s possible that bad sectors might have developed on the partition where these ISOs are stored.

Now how do I verify the integrity of those ISO files?

Is just successful opening of the file with 7zip or PowerISO enough or do I need to do something else?

I did not maintain any MD5 or SHA hash of the ISO files after creating them. May be I should have, but it did not strike me back then.

Answer (score 1):

ISO images are basically raw disk images. There is no way to check their integrity, because the ISO-9660 filesystem does not offer any data integrity verification. Indeed, most filesystems of old don’t have data integrity checks. You can only verify the filesystem itself is still intact.

So basically you could do a 2-step check:

- Verify the ISO-9660 filesystem
- Unpack/mount the image and check the files contained within, if possible

Comment: As you allude to without a checksum there is no way to check the integrity of an ISO.